# MYSQL with SUM results and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I've got this query and I want to SUM all the results of the query grouped by the column omschrijving.

The query

```
SELECT b.BoekRegelBedrag as total, c.omschrijving, ctl.vd1, b.BoekRegelId 
FROM condensations as c 
LEFT JOIN condensations_to_ledgers as ctl 
    ON ctl.vd1 = c.code
LEFT JOIN BoekstukRegels as b 
    ON b.BoekRegelGrootboekNr = ctl.GrootboekNummer 
LEFT JOIN GrootboekRekeningen as g 
    ON g.GrootboekNummer = ctl.GrootboekNummer
WHERE c.bedrijf_id = 118  
    AND b.BoekregelUserId = 118 
    AND ctl.bedrijf_id = 118 
    AND g.GrootboekUserId = 118 
    AND c.code < 10 
    AND g.BaSoort = 2
    AND b.BoekRegelPeriode BETWEEN 201000 AND 201013
 GROUP BY b.BoekRegelId
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

**EDIT**

I tried to SUM BoekRegelBedrag but then each record sums up a part in one way or the other and i got 4 results instead of one result with the total of the summed column

Comment: Could you translate those names to English as it would be easier to understand?

Comment: There's no need to decode the names into English.  There is a need to specify which column(s) should be summed in the result.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The column b.BoekRegelBedrag should be summed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've not clearly stipulated which column(s) should be summed, we have to guess.  Assuming that the BoekRegelId column should not be summed (it seldom makes sense to do arithmetic on ID numbers) — *and then not summing `ctl.vd1` per comment* — then:

```
SELECT omschrijving, SUM(total) AS sum_total
  FROM (SELECT b.BoekRegelBedrag as total, c.omschrijving, ctl.vd1, b.BoekRegelId 
          FROM condensations AS c 
          LEFT JOIN condensations_to_ledgers AS ctl
            ON ctl.vd1 = c.code
          LEFT JOIN BoekstukRegels           AS b
            ON b.BoekRegelGrootboekNr = ctl.GrootboekNummer 
          LEFT JOIN GrootboekRekeningen      AS g
            ON g.GrootboekNummer = ctl.GrootboekNummer
         WHERE c.bedrijf_id = 118  
           AND b.BoekregelUserId = 118 
           AND ctl.bedrijf_id = 118 
           AND g.GrootboekUserId = 118 
           AND c.code < 10 
           AND g.BaSoort = 2
           AND b.BoekRegelPeriode BETWEEN 201000 AND 201013
         GROUP BY b.BoekRegelId
       ) AS I
  GROUP BY omschrijving;
```

Basically, I'm using your original query result as a 'table' in the FROM clause, and then aggregating on its columns in a way which might be what you're after.

An alternative, simpler approach may also be feasible if the core query is close to what you wanted:

```
SELECT c.omschrijving, SUM(b.BoekRegelBedrag) as total
  FROM condensations AS c 
  LEFT JOIN condensations_to_ledgers AS ctl ON ctl.vd1 = c.code
  LEFT JOIN BoekstukRegels           AS b   ON b.BoekRegelGrootboekNr = ctl.GrootboekNummer 
  LEFT JOIN GrootboekRekeningen      AS g   ON g.GrootboekNummer = ctl.GrootboekNummer
 WHERE c.bedrijf_id = 118  
   AND b.BoekregelUserId = 118 
   AND ctl.bedrijf_id = 118 
   AND g.GrootboekUserId = 118 
   AND c.code < 10 
   AND g.BaSoort = 2
   AND b.BoekRegelPeriode BETWEEN 201000 AND 201013
 GROUP BY c.omschrijving;
```